# Jquery on change function not firing in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Jquery on change function not firing in asp.net MVC

**Disclaimer**: This might seem like a usual issue up front, but please bear with me and read to the end.

I have two files, namely, **CreateProject.cshtml** and **projectMasterNew.js**
**CreateProject.cshtml**

```
    
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Account.AccountName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account.AccountName, new SelectList(ViewBag.GetAccount, "AccountId", "AccountName"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account.AccountName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Account.DMName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account.DMName, new SelectList("", "DMId", "DMName"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Account.DMName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DMS/projectMasterNew.js"></script>
    <script>
        var getDmUrl = '@Url.Action("GetDMList", "Project", new { area = "Masters" })';
    </script>
```

**projectMasterNew.js**

```
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($("#Account_AccountName").val());
        $("#Account_AccountName").on("change", function () {
            alert($("#Account_AccountName").val());
            var jsonData = { account: $(this).val() };

            getJsonCall("Project Creation", getDmUrl, jsonData, function (response) {
                var dName = $('#Account_DMName');
                alert("Dropdwn update");
            });
            alert("Success");
        }, false);
    });
```

The above jquery code worked until this morning.
**Problem:**
The script was being accessed at the time of page load, since I got the alert before the function. But the change event did not trigger on when I changed the value in the AccountName dropdown.
I tried calling the change method as follows:
 1.

```
$(document).on("change", "#Account_AccountName", function () {
```

2.

```
$("#Account_AccountName").change(function () {
```

to no outcome.

So, after a little research, I implemented the below

```
    
    function DmList() {
        alert($("#Account_AccountName").val());
        var jsonData = { account: $("#Account_AccountName").val() };

        getJsonCall("Project Creation", getDmUrl, jsonData, function (response) {
            var dName = $('#Account_DMName');
            $.each(response, function (index, item) { 
                dName.append($('').text(item.DMName).val(item.DMId));
            });
            alert("Dropdwn update");
        });
        alert("Success");
    }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account.AccountName, new SelectList(ViewBag.GetAccount, "AccountId", "AccountName"), new { onchange = "DmList()"})
```

As you'll notice, the jquery function isn't called on Document Ready. That is because, adding that also threw an error

For those wondering, my **BundleConfig.cs** has

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

and my **_Layout.cshtml** has

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

I would like to know why this was an issue and what can I do to avoid such discrepancies in the future?

Comment: When you say it was working up until this morning, what has changed? Can you go back through a revision history and do a diff or a blame?

Comment: @Sanketh.K.Jain Can you share the screenshot of the html after it has rendered. You might be using the wrong ID.

Comment: where you add your `projectMasterNew.js`? I can't see it

Comment: @Sanketh.K.Jain Any console errors?

Comment: @SimonPrice There hasn't been any code change. Quite literally just came in and tried to run it.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas I checked the rendered HTML, it's the same. Hasn't changed. And no, there are no console errors either.

Comment: @Sanketh.K.Jain I suppose the problem was the false you included in the onchange function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `change` event did not fire because you had an extra `false` as the last parameter of your change event binding. I am not sure why.

Also make sure you do not have any other script errors in the page.

This should work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("#Account_AccountName").on("change", function () {
        alert($(this).val());
        var jsonData = { account: $(this).val() };
        // your get JSON call goes here

        alert("Success");
    });
});
```

Also it might be a good idea to define the `getDmUrl` variable before using it. I recommend using javascript namespacing instead of simply using a global variable.

```
<script>
     var myProj = myProj || {};
     myProj.getDmUrl = '@Url.Action("GetDMList", "Project", new { area = "Masters" })';
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DMS/projectMasterNew.js"></script>
```

And in  your `projectMasterNew.js`, use `myProj.getDmUrl` for your ajax call.